# Longest Prefix Matching

Tags: routing, router, network, networking, route

I just learnt about this concept and I have a query which was also asked by someone earlier but was grossly misinterpreted.

Suppose my Router has Routes for Networks: *192.168.22.0/23* and *192.168.22.0/25* in its routing table and if it receives a packet with destination IP address of *192.168.22.1* according to Longest Prefix Matching, it will choose the routing entry with subnet /25 and forward the packet but what if the Destination Network doesn't have the intended IP Address according to my Schema.

Wouldn't it cause connectivity/ packet drops and break my network?

I, as a Network Engineer, would have to setup my network by giving the Overlapping IPs Uniquely to the *192.168.22.0/25* Network or is it sorted/ handled in a different manner?

**Please keep in mind that I understand that I cannot configure Networks/ IP Addresses with overlapping subnets on the same router and the topology in consideration is kinda like a router connected to 2 other routers and they are connected to these networks respectively.**

Comment: If your destination network doesn't have the intended IP or a route to it, then the packet will be dropped

Answer (score 1):

If a router does not have a route to the destination network, it will drop the packet.  If the network is directly attached, the router will arp for the MAC. if there’s no response it will send a ICMP host unreachable message.

Don’t confuse routes with subnets. You can have overlapping routes but not overlapping subnets.  So 192.168.22.1 can only exist in one subnet.

Comment: Hey Ron, so I would have to keep it in mind right otherwise my packets will get dropped due to poor network topology planning?

Comment: If your subnets overlap you’ve built an invalid network.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, My subnets have not overlapped and the IP addressing is uniquely done, my query was that if my packet goes to that particular network/ subnet due to overlapping routes, and I have not used that particular IP Address in that subnet, wouldn't that cause a problem?

Comment: Basically, my packet is not reaching the intended user.

Comment: That means you have incorrect routing information. You will need more specific routes to forward the packet out the right interface

Answer (score 1):

> if it receives a packet with destination IP address of 192.168.22.1 according to Longest Prefix Matching, it will choose the routing entry with subnet /25 and forward the packet

Yes, that's how it works.

> what if the Destination Network doesn't have the intended IP Address according to my Schema

Then your network design is flawed.

Sometimes, overlapping prefixes are OK - but they might not be. It all depends on your overall design.

Having different gateways for `192.168.22.0/23` and `192.168.22.0/25` means that you want packets for `192.168.22.0/25` go one way and all *other* packets from `192.168.22.0/23` go the other way. Effectively, `192.168.22.128/23` works here as a summary route for `192.168.22.128/25`, `192.168.23.0/25`, and `192.168.23.128/25` - if you're using all of them with /25 subnets.

Note that you cannot have any IP address from `192.168.22.0/25` behind the 'other way' router. You do need to keep your addressing unambiguous and cannot have *overlapping subnets*, whatever you do.

A scenario where that routing might make sense is a branch router that attaches `192.168.22.0/23` to a larger network. It's got an uplink (possibly towards `192.168.0.0/16`) and a directly attached subnet `192.168.22.0/25`. Within that subnet is a layer-3 switch that routes between the other local subnets from `192.168.22.0/23`.

Overlapping prefixes may be counter-intuitive, so you might want to avoid them altogether. After all, somewhat modern devices usually don't mind a few more or less routing entries, and being transparent and avoiding human error may be much more important.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is very very deterministic, and routers cannot guess where to send a datagram. If a routing table has two or more than two paths toward a destination, it uses the longest match and other methods to break a tie.Routers cannot have overlapping networks that conflicts.  If a router has no path, even a default route, toward a destination, it drops the packet as undeliverable.
Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network, so router interfaces must be in different, non-overlapping networks.

Comment: Hey Alok, my router interfaces are in different/ non overlapping subnets as the subnet mask is different. I was simply trying to understand that lets say Router A & B are connected to Router C (routes of which are in consideration) Router B is connected to Network 1 and Router A is connected to Network 2. Both the Networks have some IP Overlapping but there's no IP Conflict, so due to Longest Prefix Matching, the packet is routed to Network 1 instead of Network 2, where I have used that IP Address.

Comment: router C maintain two routing table for router Aand B. Whenever packets come in router C, it conflicts(due to address overlapping) where to send router A or B , but router couldn't determine uniquely and silently discard the packets.